# How to Call a C++ Class Library From VB6

Tags: c++, com, vb6

How do I make a C++ class library COM-Visible, and call it from VB6 code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very generic question.  A lot depends on the complexity of the class you wish to expose and your familiarity with COM.  If you're already using Visual Studio, then I'd suggest exploring ATL as the shortest path to happiness.

This article should help get you started.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ax346b7(VS.80).aspx